# How to make serialization run in parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading, serialization

guys,
If I have a tree structure, and I want to serialize the tree and sub nodes. how to do the serialization for each nodes in parallel.
If I assign each node with a independent task, the output data will be disordered.
Is there some pattern for concurrent serialization?

Edit: If the structure is not a tree, but a DAG? How to handle this structure? How to serialize DAG and make the serialization to be concurrent.

Answer (score 5):

This is an ideal problem for recursive parallelism, or Fork/Join parallelism.

At each level in the tree, spawn a task to serialize each of the nodes to a temporary buffer, then wait for those tasks and join the buffers. e.g. (assuming a binary tree)

```
std::string serialize_tree(tree t)
{
     std::future<std::string> left_rep=std::async(serialize_tree,tree.left_node);
     std::future<std::string> right_rep=std::async(serialize_tree,tree.right_node);
     return left_rep.get()+right_rep.get(); // plus any further formatting
}
```

Obviously, you'll want to check for empty trees or leaf nodes, or whatever, but this should give you an idea.

EDIT: To handle a DAG, you can pass in the futures associated with the dependencies to the async calls, so each task explicitly waits for the tasks it requires to have finished.

Comment: ... and stop recursion at some depth d = O(lg #processors). +1.

Comment: That means at the end the merged string will be very huge. Such a large string will cost lots of memory, or out of memory.

Comment: Yes, for a large tree the serialized rep may well be large. It's a trade-off. You could make other choices, such as have each step serialize to a file, and join the files.

Comment: @larsmans: A good implementation of `std::async` will avoid spawning threads when there's "too many" tasks, and instead run the tasks directly in the `get()` call. If you're writing your own, then you will need to handle this limit yourself, as you indicate.

Comment: @giggle: then don't use a string, use a rope (and maybe build a string when you're done collecting). @Anthony: thanks, I guess I should read up on `std::async`.

Answer (score 0):

From your very brief description it's not clear what constraints you have so I'll answer generally.

If you want to process nodes in a tree in parallel while you want to keep the result of the processing ordered, you could do something like this.

1. Give each node a number 1-N in the order you want to have the result.
2. Give the nodes together with the assigned number to some "machinery" which can process things in parallel. Many options here how to do things.
3. Wait until all finishes and then sort the results based on the assigned number.

Here the ordering is kept by keeping the number given in #1 through the whole chain.

Step #2 could be a threadpool-backed class you just add items (number-node pairs) into.

Answer (score 0):

Running parallel jobs on a DAG is what most build tools do to compile your software.  In a single-thread/process environment, the classic solution is to order the tasks using a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) and then process the jobs in that order.

In a multi-thread/process environment, however, you must make sure that a node's task is not processed before it's dependencies are finished.  This means that you have to maintain a queue with blocking workers.  You also have to maintain the invariant that nodes in the queue are ready (their dependencies are finished processing).

One possible implementation is to maintain a dependency counter for each node; when one of its dependencies is completed, decrease the counter.  If the counter reaches 0, insert the node in the queue.